# Could a man be proved positive for a pregnancy test?

Tags: human-anatomy, pregnancy

From the question: Could a man be proved positive for a pregnancy test?. I don't mean if a man could be pregnant but if he runs a pregnancy test, it is possible for it to come out positive?

Comment: I agree the responses that beta-hCG is produced by both ovaries and testes. Males with testicular cancer can have elevated hCG levels, which could give a positive response with a pregnancy testing strip.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pregnancy test, just like any test, has some non-zero [false positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate). So yes, of course a test could be positive when a man pees on it.

Pregnancy tests work by detecting the presence of a hormone called [Beta-HCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_chorionic_gonadotropin). This hormone is produced by both genders but is produced in much higher dose during early pregnancy. Teenagers also produce a relatively high dose of [Beta-HCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_chorionic_gonadotropin) which can eventually inflate the false positive rate.

It just so happen that tumours from a particular type of testicular cancer also excrete [Beta-HCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_chorionic_gonadotropin) (see [this blog post from the American Cancer Society](https://acspressroom.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/pregnancy-test-testicular/)). If your question arises from a personal experience, then I would strongly recommend that you talk about it with your doctor.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible. Pregnancy tests detect [human chorionic gonadotropin (hCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_chorionic_gonadotropin), which in a healthy male can be produced by the pituitary gland. hCG consists of two subunits and the urine tests target a metabolite of the beta subunit. The levels of hCG in healthy adult males are below the sensitivity of pregnancy tests, they are similar to the hCG levels in non-pregnant adult females.

A postive test from a male may indicate a pathology that is elevating hCG. I know that hCG elevates during puberty but I am not sure whether the rise is sufficient to cause a positive pregnancy test.